# Netty.io messageReceived override without instanceof

Tags: java, polymorphism, netty, instanceof, visitor-pattern

In netty, MessageEvent (wrapper for messages) has a method Object getMessage() to get the real  carried message from the network. Reading the source I noticed they heavily use the **instanceof** operator to switch among methods.

However, having a wide variety of message types I would like to avoid a method like this:

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
   if (e.getMessage() instanceof MessageType1) {
      ...
   } else if (e.getMessage() instanceof MessageType2) {
      ...
   } ... {
      ...
   } else if (e.getMessage() instanceof MessageTypeN) {
      ...
   } else {
      ctx.sendUpstream(e);
   }
}
```

Writing different methods taking advantage of polymorphism would be much better, like:

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
   // MessageType implements Message
   if (e.getMessage() instanceof Message) {
      handleMessage(ctx, (Message) e.getMessage());
   } else {
      ctx.sendUpstream(e);
   }
}

void handleMessage(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageType1 m) {
    ...
}

...

void handleMessage(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageTypeN m) {
    ...
}
```

But i cannot due to downcasting limitations. Is there a clean way to do this or am I tied to **instanceof** cascade?
I could bring the logic out the Handler using .doSomething() methods inside Message sub-types but I'd like to keep the business logic inside the netty pipeline.

Comment: you can try to use Class.isAssignableFrom() or Class.isInstance() methods.

Comment: I would, however, end up to another long chain of if-else-if cascade, I'm looking for something less verbose. Those two method are anyway a valid alternative to instanceof.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved applying Visitor Pattern:

```
public interface Handler {
    void handleMessage(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageType1 m);
    void handleMessage(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageType2 m);
    ...
    void handleMessage(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageTypeN m);
}
```

then:

```
@Sharable
public class MessageHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler implements Handler {
   ...
   @Override
   public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
     if (e.getMessage() instanceof Message) {
        Message m = (Message) e.getMessage();
        m.handleTo(ctx, this);
    } else {
        ctx.sendUpstream(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageType1 m) {
    ...
}
```

and

```
public interface Message {
   /*
    * Will be {
    *    handler.handleMessage(ctx, this);
    * }
    * everywhere.
    */
   void handleTo(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Handler handler);
}
```